# Removing specific points of a 3D plot

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a 2d matrix of size 70x80. I want to plot that matrix while removing every null values.

Exemple of my matrix :

```
0.005743   0.005744
0.005741   0.005743
0.005737   0
0          0
0.005733   0.005737
```

Since the values are not varying much except for the zeros, plotting it all doesn't allow me to see the details of the values. I want to remove the zeros (just not having any values, or any tricks that will still allow me to see the details of the actual data).

[image]

Here's an idea of my values. I want to remove the wine-red section (nevermind the yellow and light-blue dots).

I have an array (Black(i,j)) knowing if a pixel is a 0 or not. I tried to build the plot point-by-point but I abandonned not seeing how that was possible.

Comment: One option is replace zeros with nan before plotting  `matrix(matrix==0)=nan` thus they will not be plotted (there will be gaps in the surface where there are)...

Comment: you could perhaps apply a transformation to the data, like plotting `log(X)`..

Answer (score 0):

try [caxis](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/caxis.html) to limit the range you want to show with color.

```
caxis([.004, .006])
```

Use [colorbar](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colorbar.html) for annotation.